Spring Boot accepts web sockets before SpringApplication.run() finished
My spring boot application accepts web sockets before SpringApplication.run() returned the ConfigurableApplicationContext. Currently I save this ConfigurableApplicationContext in a static field (maybe not nice, but not so easy to change in the current application). The function of the web socket uses this variable and therefore I run into a NullPointerException. Is there a way to prevent tomcat to accept calls before the application started completely?
